# Reading Windows Scheduled task using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I would like to know if SSIS can be used to send out notifications when a job in Windows Task Scheduler fails. Any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A c# script task could use WMI to query the status.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394601(v=vs.85).aspx

You could use a powershell script task to query the task status perhaps.

http://powershellscripttask.codeplex.com/

But then you have to install the dll on the server, which may not fly in your organization.

You can also schedule a job step in sql server with a type of powershell.